# Paypal - any differences between private and business for API

Tags: php, api, paypal, sdk

Until now I have an private Paypal account and I get many errors. Even stuff whic worked fine stop working after a while even when I don't make any changes. Like transactions aren't shown or the app just quit working and so on. Does anyone have notices any improves using business account for sandbox/live API? Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between using the two. You may be having issues with recent certificate updates depending on your server/methods of using the API. Hundreds of applications became useless unless updated to the recent G5 certificates.